# How to set the stopping criterion of Matlab's fmincon to "output.stepsize" when "active-set" algorithm is used

Tags: matlab, optimization

How can the `output.stepsize` be used as a stopping criterion for `fmincon` when using the `'active-set'` algorithm?

When I tried to solve a nonlinear constrained non-convex optimization problem, I observed that the `output.stepsize` option within `'PlotFcns'` would be a better stopping criterion than the tolerances or maximum evaluations. But in the options argument structure, there is no such option.

I also noticed that `fmincon` uses `nonlcon` to solve the problem where `output.stepsize` is calcualted.

If I don't want to change the original code of either `fmincon` or `nonlcon`, how can I set an upper limit for `output.stepsize` to use as a stopping criterion for my optimization run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that you might try to accomplish this. I'm using one of the [examples from the doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#f607434) (there's also [discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#f11675) of how to do exactly this there as well). I've simply added an [output function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#f11022) that returns `stop = true` when the `optimValues.stepsize` field reaches a threshold. I also had to make sure that this field wasn't empty, as it appears to be at initialization.

```
function fmincontest
A = [-1 -2 -2;
      1  2  2];
b = [0;72];
x0 = [10;10;10];
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','active-set','OutputFcn',@outfun);
[x,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(@myfun,x0,A,b,[],[],[],[],[],options)

function f = myfun(x)
f = -x(1)*x(2)*x(3);

function stop = outfun(x, optimValues, state)
stop = ~isempty(optimValues.stepsize) && optimValues.stepsize < 0.05;
```

If you check the `exit_flag` output from `fmincon`, you'll see that it returns `-1` now because the output function is stopping the optimization, again as indicated in the documentation. If you're already using a [plot function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#bqxk733), you can use that instead, as they have the same format.

You'll need to tailor this to your problem, adjust the threshold, and of course confirm that it works. I can't comment on how good of an idea this is. You should confirm that your error tolerances are still met satisfactorily for all cases. And I'd still want to ask why you can't specify appropriate `'TolCon'` and `'TolX'` tolerances to achieve what you need.

Comment: Very smart solution! Thank you!

Comment: I use all the following criteria 'MaxFunEvals', 'MaxFunEvals',            'MaxIter', 'TolFun', 'TolX', together; but I don't know why for my problem, 'stepsize' should be the best in most cases.